# Repopulating checkboxes in Codeigniter after Unsuccessful Form Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem repopulating a set of checkboxes after an unsuccessful form validation returns the user back to the same form. Dropdown menus and text inputs could be repopulated, but not checkboxes!

Here's a snippet of the code for the checkboxes:

```
        <td>
            <?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'casual', set_checkbox('ambience[]', 'casual')); ?> Casual <br />
            <?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'romantic', set_checkbox('ambience[]', 'romantic')); ?> Romantic <br />
            <?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'outdoor', set_checkbox('ambience[]')); ?> Outdoor / Alfresco <br />
            <?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'trendy', set_checkbox('ambience[]')); ?> Hip & Trendy <br />
            <?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'vibrant', set_checkbox('ambience[]')); ?> Vibrant <br />
            <?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'up_scale', set_checkbox('ambience[]')); ?> Upscale <br />
        </td>
```

The code snippet for text input which successfully repopulated is:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('price_range', $options, set_value('price_range')); ?>
```

Any ideas? I'm really confused why `set_checkbox` does not work as advertised.

Comment: Does it work if you use a index like ambience[0] on the first, ambience[1] on the second?

Comment: i tried using the index, and also removing the `[]` from the name, both does not work.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion about this. The brackets must always be preserved, in the form_checkbox() and set_checkbox() calls. There MUST also be a validation rule. Brackets must be include in the first set_rules() parameter. Use trim if the field is not required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You `set_checkbox` calls are wrong. When you're using an array like "ambience[]" in form_checkbox, you don't want to include the square brackets ([]) in your `set_checkbox` call. The other problem is that set_checkbox requires a second parameter which you've only included in the first 2 checkboxes.

The set_checkbox should always be like this:

```
set_checkbox('ambience', 'value');
```

Where 'value' is the second parameter of the `form_checkbox` call. Like this:

```
form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'value', set_checkbox('ambience', 'value'));
```

Comment: I did this `<?php echo form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'casual', set_checkbox('ambience', 'casual')); ?>` and the checkbox did not repopulate

Comment: I tried it on my CodeIgniter installation and it worked great. Are you sure you checked the "Casual" checkbox and not one of the others? What happens if you `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>` right above the first `echo form_checkbox(...);`? Do you see the ambience values in the array?

Comment: The codeigniter documentation does not concur with `set_checkbox('ambience', 'value');`

Answer (score 22):

In order for set_checkbox to work properly, an actual validation rule needs to be used on that element.  I ran into this problem and could not get the value to show on a resubmit until I included:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('checkbox_name', 'checkbox_title', 'trim');
```

Then, everything worked perfect.

Comment: I agree. You need to validate it (even if it's only 'trim') for it to work.

Comment: +1 For being the only answer that explains that you need a validation rule for set_checkbox to work. Not even the Codeigniter documentation is clear about this. It looks like the same is true for set_value for checkboxes as well.

Comment: Since the OP said that the above answer was accepted I can't help but feel that is inaccurate. If you are using the form validation i.e. `form_validation->run()` has happened somewhere then I believe is the correct answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy.

Comment: I wish this was in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I actually found that it only works if you use like this:

```
form_checkbox('ambience[]', 'value', set_checkbox('ambience[]', 'value'));
```

You need the square array brackets on the name for it to work properly.

Comment: your answer is actually wrong. You cant use the square brackets in set_checkbox('ambience[]').

Comment: Actually he is not wrong.  In order to post an array of checkbox values and remember which ones were checked, the square brackets must be in set_checkbox, also in the name of the checkbox and also in the $this->form_validation->set_rules in the controller.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working example. You are required to include the array name **with brackets []** in each of `$this->form_validation->set_rules()`, `form_checkbox()` and `set_checkbox()`.

In the controller:

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('set_reminder_days[]', 'Reminder Day', 'trim');

    if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) //Field validation failed.
    {
        //form validation errors will show up automatically
    }
    else //Validation success.
    {
        //This is an array of all checked checkboxes
        $reminder_days = $this->input->post('set_reminder_days');
    }
```

In the view:

```
    $day_options = array(
        'S' => 'Sunday',
        'M' => 'Monday',
        'T' => 'Tuesday',
        'W' => 'Wednesday',
        'Th' => 'Thursday',
        'F' => 'Friday',
        'Sa' => 'Saturday'
    );

    foreach( $day_options as $key => $day_option ) {
        echo form_checkbox('set_reminder_days[]', $key, set_checkbox('set_reminder_days[]', $key), 'class="form-checkbox"');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. This is really working. I have tried both set_reminder_days[] and set_reminder_days in form_validation parameters, it doesn't matter. Another I realized is remember to use POST method, GET method somehow doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that set_checkbox takes 3 parameters :

```
 set_checkbox(string $checkboxname, string $value, boolean $isChecked);
```

For example :

```
 echo form_checkbox('mycbx[]',
                    $item['id'],
                    set_checkbox('mycbx[]', $item['id'], false)
      );
```

or this way :

```
$checkbox = array(
    'name'        => 'mycbx[]',
    'value'       => $item['id'],
    'checked'     => set_checkbox('mycbx[]', $item['id'], false)
);
echo form_checkbox($checkbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not use form helper. I try to use this code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tes_display" value="1" <?php echo set_checkbox('tes_display', '1', FALSE); ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_checkbox_array($field, $value)
{
    $arr = isset($_POST[$field]) ? $_POST[$field] : FALSE;
    return ($arr !== FALSE && is_array($arr) && in_array($value, $arr)) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions here none worked. So i collected all the data, packed it into an array, then use a loop to check if the values in the array match the value of the selected box, if so change the checked attribute to checked.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="col-sm-10 tags">
    <label>
        <input class="tags" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="love" >Love                            
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="tags" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="God" >God
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="tags" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="Reality" >Reality
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="tags" type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="Entrepreneurship">Entrepreneurship
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code in a function

```
(function(){
    var tag_string = '<?php echo $_post['tags']; ?>',
        tags = tag_string.split(', ');
    boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('tags');
    for(i = 0; i< boxes.length;i++ ){
        if(tags.toString().includes(boxes[i].value)){
            boxes[i].checked = "checked";
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, I have used it as follows:

In the view I did:

```
$checkbox_name = 'menu_type_id[]';
$menu_type_attributes = array(
  'name'              => 'menu_type_id[]',
  'id'                => 'menu_type_id',
  'class'             => 'checkbox-custom rectangular',
  'value'             => $menu_type->get_id(), 
  'checked'           => set_checkbox('menu_type_id[]', $menu_type->get_id()),                 
  'aria-describedby'  => 'menuTypeIdHelp'
);
echo form_checkbox($menu_type_attributes);
```

In the controller I have the validation (FYI, you will have to have form validation on the checkbox if you want to retain the checked status of the checkbox)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('menu_type_id[]', 'Menu type(s)', 'required');
```

Even though your business rule does not require you to have at least one checkbox checked, you will still need to put a validation for the checkbox. For eg, you could use

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('menu_type_id[]', 'Menu type(s)', 'trim');` etc.

Hope this will help some one out there, b/c this information is not available in Code Igniter's documentation.